# Using optimize to get the maximum of a plot

Tags: r

I'm trying to use function optimize to get the maximum of a plot (concretely of a maximum likelihood plot):

I'm using the following code:

```
optimize(f=fml, interval = c(-10,10), maximum = TRUE)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in f(arg, ...) : unused argument (arg)
```

The function fml is:

```
fml<-function(){
q1<- Nominal(z, a, c, x[1])
q2<- Nominal(z, a, c, x[2])
p3<- Nominal(z, a, c, x[3])
q4<- Nominal(z, a, c, x[4])
p1<- 1 - q1
p2<- 1 - q2
p4<- 1 - q4
p <- p1*p2*p3*p4
q <- 1-p
ML <- log(p*q)
plot(x= z, y=ML)
}
```

Nominal is another function that extracts only probabilities. The function fml works properly cause I get this plot, and it obviously has a maximum. See image below:

[image]

What could be the error?

EDIT:

Variables are:

```
a1 <- c(-0.5,-1,-0.3,-1.2)
a2 <- c(-0.2,0.3,-0.6,0.4)
a3 <- c(0.7,0.7,0.9,0.8)
a <- rbind(a1,a2,a3)
c1 <- c(0.2,0.3,-0.4,-0.6)
c2 <- c(0.7,0.3,1.6,-0.4)
c3 <- c(-0.9,-0.6,-1.2,1)
c <- rbind(c1,c2,c3)
x <- c(2,1,3,2)
z<- seq(-10,10,0.001)
```

And nominal function is:

```
Nominal <- function(z, av, cv, x){
K <- length(av)
suma <- 0
for(k in 1: K){suma <- suma + exp(z*av[k] + cv[k])}
exp(z*av[x] + cv[x])/suma
}
```

Comment: `optimize` searches for a maximum of a function y=f(x) by trying various values of x. Your function `fml` _takes no argument_ . There is no place for `optimize` to give it x's to try.

Comment: And how could I create an argument for searching to the points in the plot?

Comment: We can't tell very well from your question. Your function depends on `Nominal` which you don't show us and also on z,a,c & x that you also do not show us. Your function creates a plot.  You need a function f that takes a numeric argument x and produces a numeric result y - like sin(x) or y = x^2 + 1

Comment: Solved: I added to the function `max<-which.max(ML)` and `print(z[max])`, so I don't need to use optimize with that function now! Thanks @G5W